# Vue, how to handle reactivity with deeply nested objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I have an Object that I'm manipulating as shown below:

```
const posts = [
    { key1: "abc", key2: [{ innerKey1: "def", innerKey2: 123 }, { innerKey1: "def", innerKey2: 123 }] },
    { key1: "abc", key2: [{ innerKey1: "def", innerKey2: 123 }, { innerKey1: "def", innerKey2: 123 }] },
    { key1: "abc", key2: [{ innerKey1: "def", innerKey2: 123 }, { innerKey1: "def", innerKey2: 123 }] },
];

posts[0].key2[1].innerKey1 = "newVal";
```

The Array in `key2` is a prop where the inner keys are expected to mutate. I want to maintain reactivity when `innerKey1` or `innerKey2` change.

Because Vue has difficulty detecting changes in Arrays and Objects as discussed [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats), we cannot modify Arrays by their indexes or Objects by their keys directly.

In order to retain reactivity, it seems we need some complex logic using `Vue.set()` to set `newVal`:

I'm thinking along the lines of:

`Vue.set(posts, 1, Vue.set(key2, 0, Vue.set(innerKey1, "newVal")))`

Is this the best way to maintain reactivity here, or is there something I'm missing that can make this easier?

Note:
I've also tried using a deep watcher in my child component to observe changes that occur in the `key2` array. But it doesn't seem capable of observing those changes.

```
//ChildComponent.vue
<html>
  <div>
   <RandomComponent v-for="thing in key2" :key... :innerKey2="thing.innerKey2">
  </div>
</html>

<script>
props: {
    key2: {
        type: Array,
        require: true,
    },
},
watch: {
    key2: {
        immediate: true,
        deep: true,
        handler () {
            console.log("Watcher working"); //Does not fire when parent mutates innerKeys
        },
    },
},
</script>
```

Comment: Modifying arrays by indexes is a mistake here, this doesn't trigger reactivity. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said in my post. That's why I suggested replacing it with `Vue.set(posts, 1, Vue.set(key2, 0, Vue.set(innerKey1, "newVal")))` and linked that same page. I'll clarify that some more, it seems I wasn't clear

Comment: It's that, or using array methods to replace an element, i.e. with `splice`.

Comment: sometimes we also see things like this: `this.array = [...this.array, newItem]` or `this.array = this.array.filter(etc)`

Comment: Ah I see, creating a new array altogether -- how would you implement that, in this specific case, to modify one of the innerKeys here? @TheFool

Comment: do the same technique but start higher up. `this.outerData  = complexFuncToGetNewOuterData(this.outerData)`

Comment: How do I replace one deeply nested object with another completely different deeply nested object, and have Vue to re-render the whole nested tree???

Answer (score 0):

I sense a lack of clarity in the question.

- If you want to update just a property of an **existing array element** mutating by index should work fine without any workaround.

i.e This should be reactive

```
posts[0].key2[1].innerKey1 = "newVal";
```

- However, If you are trying to **replace** the array **element** you need a workaround for the Vue reactivity issue explained [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays)

I think the cleanest workaround for your case is using `Array.splice` to replace the element. (for example after network response)

```
  const postId = 0 // the root element 
  const updatePost = { ...this.posts[postId] }
  updatePost.key2[1].innerKey1 = 'newVal'

  this.posts.splice(postId, 1, updatedPost);
```

Here is an illustration  I made on [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-thunder-82zkm?file=/src/App.vue)